# How do I toggle dark mode in a flutter app

Tags: flutter, themes, darkmode

I have a flutter app which has some code like the following:

```
MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(/*...*/)
)
```

and a ThemeData(). However, I don't want the Scaffold's `child` Widget to be rebuilt and it doesn't have a const constructor either. I know that I can wrap the scaffold in a new widget and set its state but that would rebuild the children! What do I do?

Comment: What is the problem with the rebuild ? Can you please explain what exact behaviour you want ?

Comment: I have a bunch of `TextInputFields` and I don't wan't to rebuild them because it would cause the fields to be cleared. Along with that, some pages have `ListView.builder` and rebuilding them would mean re-importing a lot of data from the internet due to my structure and scrolling would be lost. Al I want is that the scaffold's background color changes to black and the text to white.

Comment: If you don't want your widget to rebuild, maybe you can pass the same key every-time. And flutter will make sure it is not re-drawn.

Comment: @Nitesh There are a lot of textboxes and it will be inconvenient/slow because the Navigator stack is also very large and I wan't my app to be convienient because it will also be displaying hindi text.